# Power BI Table Visual Column Limit

Tags: powerbi

I am using dynamic Field Parameters to show columns in a table visual in my Power BI report. There is 200+ columns in my table. The maximum I am able to show and export to excel from the table is 167 columns. I am not sure how it is happening, or if there is a limitation on the number of columns, we can show in the visual using field parameters.

Does anyone know about this? Didn't find anything on Microsoft Learn's pages.